# Convert a flat Spark datafame into a structured one in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm pulling data from a relational database into a DynamoDB export format, so I need to to "unflatten" my data

What's the best way to transform my DataFrame from this:

```
root
 |-- Item.column1.S: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item.column2.S: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item.column3.S: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item.column4.S: string (nullable = true)
```

Into this?

```
root
 |-- Item: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be, in addition to transforming the dataset schema, to build a custom Spark transformer to unfold the the data.

Let´s consider a new class that takes as input the number of items per column:

```
class SparkCustomTransformer(numColumnsPerItem: Int) {

  assert(
    numColumnsPerItem <= 3,
    "No more than 3 items per column are allowed"
  )

  /** Add all code here **/
}
```

Inside the class above, there are two functions that create the old schema and another to create the new one:

```
def oldSchema() = {
  StructType(1 to numColumnsPerItem map { i =>
    StructField(s"Item.column$i.S", StringType)
  })
}

def newSchema(oldSchema: StructType) = {
  val newSchema = oldSchema.fields.map { case StructField(name, _, _, _) =>
    val Array(item, column, s) = name.split('.')
    (item, StructType(List(
      StructField(column, StructType(List(StructField(s, StringType)))))))
  }

  StructType(
    newSchema.map { case (name, v) => StructField(name, v) }
  )
}
```

A Spark struct type can be easily handled as Scala case classes, although depending of the number of items per column a number of different case clases for must be created. There are more advanced features using some parts of generic programming to avoid them, however I will put an example using at most three items per column.

```
case class Column(S: String)

trait Item
case class Item1(column1: Column) extends Item
case class Item2(column1: Column, column2: Column) extends Item
case class Item3(column1: Column, column2: Column, column3: Column)
  extends Item

def convert1(in: List[String]): Item1 = Item1(Column(in(0)))
def convert2(in: List[String]): Item2 = Item2(Column(in(0)), 
Column(in(1)))

def convert3(in: List[String]): Item3 =
  Item3(Column(in(0)), Column(in(1)), Column(in(2)))

def udf1 = udf { in: String => convert1(List(in)) }
def udf2 = udf { (in0: String, in1: String) => convert2(List(in0, in1)) }
def udf3 = udf { (in0: String, in1: String, in2: String) =>
  convert3(List(in0, in1, in2))
}
```

Note that I use udfs here, I don´t know if there is a solution using sql expressions, so I decided to do it in that way.

For data transformation I create a Spark custom transformer:

```
def transformer = new Transformer {

  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    numColumnsPerItem match {
      case 1 =>
        dataset
          .withColumnRenamed("Item.column1.S", "Item_column1_S")
          .withColumn("Item", udf1(col("Item_column1_S")))
          .withColumnRenamed("Item_column1_S", "Item.column1.S")
      case 2 =>
        dataset
          .withColumnRenamed("Item.column1.S", "Item_column1_S")
          .withColumnRenamed("Item.column2.S", "Item_column2_S")
          .withColumn(
            "Item",
            udf2(col("Item_column1_S"), col("Item_column2_S"))
          )
          .withColumnRenamed("Item_column1_S", "Item.column1.S")
          .withColumnRenamed("Item_column2_S", "Item.column2.S")
      case 3 =>
        dataset.withColumn(
          "Item",
          udf3(
            col("Item.column1.S"),
            col("Item.column2.S"),
            col("Item.column3.S")
          )
        )
    }
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Transformer = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    newSchema(oldSchema())
  }

  override val uid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString

}
```

Once again, more elegant approaches can be created deriving the transformer using compiler implicit resolution, but the solution using a simple pattern matching works. Note that **I had to change the name of the columns**, there is a bug related to column names which include dots using udfs.

Note that the transformer transforms the old schema to the new one.

An example:

```
val transformer = new SparkCustomTransformer(2)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("Element", "Element2"))),
  transformer.oldSchema()
)

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

It gives the input dataframe:

```
root
 |-- Item.column1.S: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item.column2.S: string (nullable = true)
```

Applying the transformer:

```
val df0 = transformer.transformer.transform(df)
df0.printSchema()
df0.show(false)
```

It shows the result:

```
root
 |-- Item: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)

+-----------------------+
|Item                   |
+-----------------------+
|[[Element], [Element2]]|
+-----------------------+
```

As I said before, Scala has the capabilities of doing this process more generic and elegant. There are a lot of possibilities.